# Codenameone How to externalize the Location object

Tags: codenameone

I receive following error message when I try to add Location for externalization. Please advise how to externalize the Location object. Please advise.
See the code used for Storage and Externalization
code:

```
addOfflineCommand("location", latitude, longitude, time1);

latitude - double data type;
longitude - double data type;
time1 - long data type;

private void addOfflineCommand(String name, Object... args) {
List<OfflineCommand> l_noAppt = (List<OfflineCommand>) 
Storage.getInstance().readObject(appName + user + "-offlineCommandsLocEnc");
l_noAppt.add(new OfflineCommand(name, args));
}
```

Please see the Error Message below:

```
[EDT] 0:4:37,444 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Object type not supported: com.codename1.location.Location value: altitude = 1000.0
latitude40.714353
longtitude-74.00597299999998
direction0.0
timeStamp1529000278457
velocity50.0
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:562)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:595)
at com.X.Xmobile.server.OfflineCommand.internalize(OfflineCommand.java:40)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:689)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:664)
at com.codename1.io.Storage.readObject(Storage.java:261)
at com.X.Xmobile.server.ServerImpl.addOfflineCommand(ServerImpl.java:1165)
at com.X.Xmobile.server.ServerImpl.finishActivity(ServerImpl.java:1504)
at com.X.Xmobile.forms.CommentForm.lambda$new$3(CommentForm.java:70)

java.io.IOException: Object type not supported: com.codename1.location.Location value: altitude = 1000.0
latitude40.714353
longtitude-74.00597299999998
direction0.0
timeStamp1529000278457
velocity50.0
at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:457)
at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:394)
at com.X.Xmobile.server.OfflineCommand.externalize(OfflineCommand.java:34)
at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:258)
at com.codename1.io.Util.writeObject(Util.java:286)
at com.codename1.io.Storage.writeObject(Storage.java:224)
at com.X.Xmobile.server.ServerImpl.addOfflineCommand(ServerImpl.java:1201)
at com.X.Xmobile.server.ServerImpl.finishActivity(ServerImpl.java:1504)

[EDT] 0:6:4,551 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Object type not supported: com.co
```

Following is the class OfflineCommand class created which is used for externalization.

```
public class OfflineCommand implements Externalizable {
private static final int VERSION = 1;
private String name;
private Object[] arguments;
public OfflineCommand() {}

public OfflineCommand(String name, Object... args) {
    this.name = name;
    this.arguments = args;
}

@Override
public int getVersion() {
    return VERSION;
}

@Override
public void externalize(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    Util.writeUTF(name, out);
    Util.writeObject(arguments, out);
}

@Override
public void internalize(int version, DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    name = Util.readUTF(in);
    arguments = (Object[])Util.readObject(in);
}

@Override
public String getObjectId() {
    return "OfflineCommand";
}  

public String getName() {
    return name;
}  

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} 

public Object[] getArguments() {
    return arguments;
}  
public void setArguments(Object[] arguments) {
    this.arguments = arguments;
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Location` isn't externalizable. It doesn't support object serialization explicitly. Normally you would need to convert the write/read data to work with the location data instead of the location object. However, since your code is generic you would need to extend location to implement externalizable.

```
public class ExternalizableLocation extends Location implements Externalizable {
    // implement the externalizable interface here...
}
```

In your `init(Object)` class register `ExternalizableLocation` as externalizable and in every place where you store a `Location` object replace it with `ExternalizableLocation`.